# How close method in case we need to cancel any streams with Bloc in dispose?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I need to call a method to reset a timer in the block when destroying a widget, but I'm having an error when doing this. I tried as follows:

I've tried using didChangeDependencies() but it wouldn't work as I want. I need to cancel the timer only when destroying the widget. Could someone help me?

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _timer.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
```

calling on dispose:

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    BlocProvider.of<MyBlocName>(context).close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

It throws the following error:

> Exception has occurred.
> FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
> At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)